# MySQL join query, can't figure it out

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `questions` and `questions_lookup`. Users vote if it's a good question or not to put on the site.

```
table: questions
    id
    question
    date_created
table: questions_lookup
    id
    question_id // (id linked to questions table)
    user_id // (the id of the user, I store this in a session variable called $me)
    show // (1 or 0, show or don't show)
```

I would like to have a php page that pulls all the questions from the questions table ordered by their date_created and then display if the user has answered it or not.  When I attempt to do any joins, I end up having duplicate questions show because it will pull other user's answers.

So if there are 10 questions.  And a particular user has only answered 3.  We still display all 10 questions, but mark the ones that they've answered.

So I essentially want to display something like:

```
Question 1
Question 2 (answered)
Question 3 (answered)
Question 4
Question 5
Question 6
Question 7 (answered)
Question 8
Question 9
Question 10
```

I've tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM questions
RIGHT JOIN questions_lookup
ON (questions.id = questions_lookup.question_id)
WHERE questions_lookup.user_id = '$me'
ORDER BY questions.date_created DESC
```

Comment: Can you post your SQL query to retrieve the 10 Q list?

Comment: I just updated it with the query I was trying.

Comment: What is the purpose of `show` field?

Comment: the 'show' field is the user voting on whether or not to show the question on the site.  so they can either vote yes (1) that the question should be on the site, or (0) no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT q.*, 
       l.user_id,
       l.show,
       IF(l.question_id IS NULL,'','answered') as answered
  FROM questions q LEFT JOIN
       questions_lookup l ON q.id = l.question_id AND
                             l.user_id = 5 <-- user id goes here
 ORDER BY q.date_created DESC
```

You can play with with the calculated `answered` column, depending on what output you really need for further processing:

```
IF(l.question_id IS NULL,'','answered') as answered <-- 'answered' if answered, empty string if not (like in your example)
IFNULL(l.question_id,0) as answered <-- question_id (if autogenerated unsigned  int will be > 0) if answered, 0-if not
```

or as GolezTrol suggeested

```
CASE WHEN ql.question_id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END as answered <-- yes if answered and no if not
```

Comment: i think this one is working!  I'm going to test it some more.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, assuming there can only be one record per user per question in `questions_lookup`.

```
select
  q.*,
  case when ql.question_id is null then
    'no'
  else
    'yes'
  end as user_has_answered
from
  questions q
  left join questions_lookup ql 
    on ql.question_id = q.id
    and ql.user_id = 5 /* User id of current user */
```

The trick is to query all `questions` and `left join` the `questions_lookup`. By adding the user_id to the join condition, you will leave out records of other users, while still returning the questions that don't have a record for the current user. If you move `ql.user_id = 5` to a where clause, the query will no longer work, because it would effectively turn your left join into an inner join.

[edit]

I see you have added your query. Two mistakes there. Right join should be left join, because you always want to have a record on the left (questions), and optional records on the right (lookup). Also, the condition should not be in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
SELECT questions.*, max(questions_lookup.show) AS show 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN questions_lookup ON questions_lookup.question_id=questions.id 
WHERE (questions_lookup.user_id='youruserid' OR questions_lookup.user_id IS NULL) 
GROUP BY questions.id 
ORDER BY questions.date_created ASC
```

Then in your results, `show=1` means the user has answered.

Comment: This one is not showing all the questions.  It's missing the ones the user hasn't answered (not in the questions_lookup table)